# Get Scala type name for common AnyVal types/primitives

Tags: scala, types, runtime-type, treehugger

In my scala code I have a `Class[_ <: AnyVal]` instance, such as the one obtained from `classOf[Int]`.

When I try to obtain the scala type name from this (using `classOf[Int].getName`), I am expecting to see `"scala.Int"`, but instead I am getting the primitive Java type's name: `"int"`

How can I get the scala type name from my `Class` variable, in case I am dealing with either a java primitive equivalent, or the default boxed java equivalent (such as `java.lang.Integer`)

---

In case you are wondering why I would need this; I am generating some scala code using treehugger, and the information about whether I need to generate e.g. a `scala.Int` comes from a library that provides a `Class[_]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to handle primitive types,

```
def scalaName(cls: Class[_]) = 
  if (cls.isPrimitive) s"scala.${cls.getName.capitalize}" else cls.getName
```

Unfortunately the Java standard library doesn't (still, as far as I know) provide a way to convert between boxed and primitive `Class`es, so the best way is to handle them all individually:

```
val classesMap = Map[Class[_], Class[_]](
  classOf[java.lang.Integer] -> classOf[Int], 
  classOf[java.lang.Short] -> classOf[Short], 
  ...
)

def scalaName1(cls: Class[_]) = scalaName(classesMap.getOrElse(cls, cls))
```

You may also want to handle `Void.TYPE` specifically (e.g. converting to `scala.Unit`).